# Using BindingList for DataGridView

Tags: powershell

i'm completly new to Powershell so i can't figure out what format DataGridView.Datasource is expecting. All documentation i found was for C#.

Here is my code so far:

```
$DataGrid = new-object System.windows.forms.DataGridView

$TestArray=@{Name='Chirag';EmpID="001";City="Pune"}
$DataBindingList = New-Object System.ComponentModel.BindingList[object] 
$DataBindingList.Add($TestArray)
$DataBindingList.Add($TestArray)
$DataBindingList.Add($TestArray)
$DataBindingList.Add($TestArray)

$Datagrid.DataSource = $DataBindingList
```

I used an ArrayList at first as DataSource and while that worked for displaying the data it disabled adding or removing rows. When i tried the error told me to implement IBindingList.
But my current code just displays what seems like meta-data.

Comment: Your code is again correct, but `$TestArray` in your example is actually a `hashtable` and what you're seeing in your DGV are actually it's Properties. Try using a `PSCustomObject` instead and all will be fine: `[pscustomobject]@{Name='Chirag';EmpID="001";City="Pune"}`

Comment: Regarding not being able to edit if using an `ArrayList` I'm not sure what you mean, it works perfectly fine with it too. DGV allows editing and DataSource gets updated properly

Comment: Well, using `PSCustomObject`  works for displaying and deleting data, but adding throws a `PsArgumentException`. And Regarding the ArrayList. When i use it, it just disables changing the table dimensions completly. I can still edit the content, but the button for adding rows is just gone. If i understand the documentation for `DataGridView.AllowUserToDeleteRows` - Section "Remarks" correctly, that is expected.

Comment: You might need to provide a minimal reproducible example of your code in a new question regarding the deleting rows error